# Prove that a linearly independent set of two vectors in R^3 and one of the standard basis vectors is a linearly independent set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the linearly independent set $\{v,w\}$ where both $v$ and $w$ are in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now consider the sets
$$\{v,w,e_1\}, \quad \{v,w,e_2\}, \quad \{v,w,e_3\}$$ where $e_i$ are standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$. I believe that exactly two of the above sets are linearly dependent, and exactly one is not. I am looking for a way to prove this with minimal hand-waving. I have thought about proving it by contradiction, assuming that all of them are linearly dependent, which would imply that $\{v,w\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ since each standard basis vector is in its span. However, this only proves that at least one of the sets is linearly dependent, how would I show that it is **exactly** one?

Comment: Your guess is wrong - but you are correct that at least one of these sets must be linearly independent.

Comment: But, if $v=e_1$ and $w=e_2$ the three sets are linearly independent.

Comment: That’s technically true, but linear independence is really a property of a multi-set of vectors. @Azif00

Comment: What happens if $v=e_1-e_2$ and $w=e_1-e_3$? More generally, take any two vectors that span a plane that doesn’t include any of the standard basis vectors.

Comment: Ah I see, all the sets will be linearly independent right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Gram-Schmidt process, which turns a linearly indept set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ of vectors into a set of vectors $\{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ such that (a) the span of $\{u_1, \ldots, u_j\}$ is the span of $\{v_1, \ldots, v_j\}$ for every $j$, and (b) the vectors of the $u$-set are orthonormal, then it's worth knowing you can generalize it to handle a linearly **de**pendent input set. In that form, some of the $u$-vectors will be zero, but the nonzero ones will be orthonormal, and all the other parts hold.

That generalized form is this:

for i = 1 to k ...

1. Compute $w_i = v_i - \sum_{1\le j < i} (v_i \cdot u_j) u_j$
2. If $w_i$ is the zero vector, let $u_i$ be zero as well. Otherwise, let $u_i = \frac{1}{\|w_i\|}w_i$.

When you're done, you'll have a set $\{u_1, \ldots, u_k\}$ of vectors, some of which are zero, and others of which are unit vectors. Throw out the zero vectors, and you've got the result you need.

Now...to solve your problem, consider the set $\{v, w, e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ and apply this generalized GS process to it. Because the last three vectors span all of 3-space, clearly the result will do so. But after you've processed the first two vectors, you've got two vectors that span a plane; thus when you process either $e_1, e_2,$ or $e_3$, the resulting span must grow by one dimension. Whichever one does that -- say $e_p$, then you know that $\{v, w, e_p\}$ spans all of $\Bbb R^3$. (Of course, some other $e_i$ might work as well, but that's not what's asked!)

Answer (score 1):

If $v=e_1, w=e_2$ then exactly one of the sets is linearly independent.

If $v=e_1,v=e_2+e_3$, then exactly two of the sets are linearly independent.

If $v=e_1+e_2$ and $w=e_2+e_3$, then the sets are all linearly independent.

So there are many possibilities, and we cannot say without more information exactly how many of the sets are linearly independent.

However, at least one of them must be linearly independent. Consider, for instance, if the first two are linearly dependent. Then $e_1$ is some linear combination of $v$ and $w$, while $e_2$ is some other linear combination of $v$ and $w$. Then $v$ and $w$ span the $xy$-plane, and therefore $\{v,w,e_3\}$ is linearly independent.